# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "¿"

Tags: sql

I am trying to make sure that my primary key auto increments. The code below is what I have tried so far.

```
create or replace trigger field_null
  before insert on table        
   for each row 
begin  
  if :new.number_id is null then
    select number_id_SEQ.nextval into :new.number_id from table;
 end if;
 end;​
```

Comment: I am confused on how the title matches the question haha

Answer (score 1):

Instead of table in select query,try to use dual. Try this General Trigger syntax to create trigger for Auto-increment column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER %triggername%
BEFORE INSERT ON %tablename% FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT %seqname%.NEXTVAL
  INTO :NEW.%columnname%
  FROM DUAL;
END;
```

`%seqname%` will be replaced with the name of the sequence.

`%triggername%` will be replaced with the name of the trigger.

`%columnname%` will be replaced with the name of the associated column.

And to Create Sequence, You can use the following syntax:-

```
CREATE SEQUENCE %seqname%
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

[Refer Here](http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html)

Comment: it says that the trigger is invalid

Comment: @bev :- see modified answer